# Does kubectl port-forward ignore loadBalance services?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

My Environment: Mac dev machine with latest Minikube/Docker

I built (locally) a simple docker image with a simple Django REST API "hello world".I'm running a deployment with 3 replicas. This is my `yaml` file for defining it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myproj-app-service
  labels:
    app: myproj-be
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8000
  selector:
    app: myproj-be
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myproj-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: myproj-be
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myproj-be
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myproj-be
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myproj-app-server
          image: myproj-app-server:4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_URL
              value: postgres://myname:@10.0.2.2:5432/myproj2
            - name: REDIS_URL
              value: redis://10.0.2.2:6379/1
```

When I apply this `yaml` it generates things correctly.
  - one deployment
  - one service
  - three pods

Deployments:

```
NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
myproj-app-deployment   3/3     3            3           79m
```

Services:

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          83m
myproj-app-service   LoadBalancer   10.96.91.44   <pending>     8000:31559/TCP   79m
```

Pods:

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myproj-app-deployment-77664b5557-97wkx   1/1     Running   0          48m
myproj-app-deployment-77664b5557-ks7kf   1/1     Running   0          49m
myproj-app-deployment-77664b5557-v9889   1/1     Running   0          49m
```

The interesting thing is that when I `SSH` into the `Minikube`, and hit the service using `curl 10.96.91.44:8000` it respects the `LoadBalancer` type of the service and rotates between all three pods as I hit the endpoints time and again. I can see that in the returned results which I have made sure to include the HOSTNAME of the pod.

However, when I try to access the service from my Hosting Mac -- using `kubectl port-forward service/myproj-app-service 8000:8000` -- Every time I hit the endpoint, I get the same pod to respond. It doesn't load balance. I can see that clearly when I `kubectl logs -f <pod>` to all three pods and only one of them is handling the hits, as the other two are idle...

Is this a `kubectl port-forward` limitation or issue? or am I missing something greater here?

Comment: Just a note that the `LoadBalancer` isn't doing anything here when you are `curl`ing the ClusterIP. The Service itself will do TCP level, new connection sharing between pods. This is managed on each node individually in a cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that my pods were randomly in a crashing state due to Python *.pyc files that were left in the container. This causes issues when Django is running in a multi-pod Kubernetes deployment. Once I removed this issue and all pods ran successfully, the round-robin started working.

Comment: I have the same issues now. But i used springboot and no pods where crashing?

Comment: same issue as @huy

Answer (score 18):

`kubectl port-forward` looks up the first Pod from the Service information provided on the command line and forwards directly to a Pod rather than forwarding to the ClusterIP/Service port. The cluster doesn't get a chance to load balance the service like regular service traffic.

The kubernetes API only provides [Pod port forward operations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#create-connect-portforward-pod-v1-core) (`CREATE` and `GET`). Similar API operations don't exist for Service endpoints.

#### `kubectl` code

Here's a little bit of the flow from the `kubectl` code that seems to back that up (I'll just add that Go isn't my primary language)

The [portforward.go `Complete` function](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/c53c16a548eb34f54f673efee2b9b09c52ec15b5/pkg/cmd/portforward/portforward.go#L225) is where `kubectl portforward` does the first look up for a pod from options via [`AttachablePodForObjectFn`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/c53c16a548eb34f54f673efee2b9b09c52ec15b5/pkg/cmd/portforward/portforward.go#L254):

The `AttachablePodForObjectFn` is defined as `attachablePodForObject` in [this interface](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/6d12ae1ac20bee2d3b5fb7a664de76d7fc134a63/pkg/polymorphichelpers/interface.go#L39-L40), then here is the [`attachablePodForObject` function](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/6d12ae1ac20bee2d3b5fb7a664de76d7fc134a63/pkg/polymorphichelpers/attachablepodforobject.go).

To my (inexperienced) Go eyes, it appears the [`attachablePodForObject`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/6d12ae1ac20bee2d3b5fb7a664de76d7fc134a63/pkg/polymorphichelpers/attachablepodforobject.go) is the thing `kubectl` uses to look up a Pod to from a Service defined on the command line.

Then from there on everything deals with filling in the Pod specific [`PortForwardOptions`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/c53c16a548eb34f54f673efee2b9b09c52ec15b5/pkg/cmd/portforward/portforward.go#L46-L58) (which doesn't include a service) and is passed to the kubernetes API.

Comment: It looks like you might always forward to the [first active pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/3874cf79897cfe1e070e592391792658c44b78d4/pkg/polymorphichelpers/attachablepodforobject.go#L51-L52) as well, even if you try to attach again.