# Readiness Probe fails but Port-forward to service works

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I have a deployment.yaml which has a readiness probe on the container. (The readiness probe is intended to fail here)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: my-nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        readinessProbe:
         exec:
          command:
            - cat
            - /server/xyz.txt
         initialDelaySeconds: 50
         periodSeconds: 10
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

The pods in the deployment are served using a service of type ClusterIP.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx-service
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

after applying these yamls using `kubectl apply`, container in the pods is never ready as the readiness probe is failing, which is expected.

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-nginx-deployment-6b788b89c6-f69j7   0/1     Running   0          9m50s
my-nginx-deployment-6b788b89c6-m5qf6   0/1     Running   0          9m50s
```

So since these pods are not ready, they should not serve the traffic but when I do

```
kubectl port-forward services/nginx-service 8086:8080
```

I am able to get 200 response and nginx home page on `http://127.0.0.1:8086/` and I can also see  pods logs about serving traffic.

question is, why pods are serving traffic when readiness probe is failing.

PS: I have created cluster on my machine using Kind

Comment: How is this question related to programming? It might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does kubectl port-forward ignore loadBalance services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940833/does-kubectl-port-forward-ignore-loadbalance-services)

Answer (score 1):

The `port-forward` [api](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#create-connect-portforward-pod-v1-core) is for a Pod. The `kubectl port-forward` command just use *service* to make it easy to use, but your port are actually forwarded to a Pod - so the *readiness* status is not applicable.