# Kubelet still sending requests even after springboot readiness probes is in REFUSING_TRAFFIC stage

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I was trying readiness probe in kubernetes with a springboot app. After the app starts, lets say after 60 seconds I fire `ReadinessState.REFUSING_TRAFFIC` app event.

I use port-forward for kubernetes service(Cluster-Ip) and checked /actuator/health/readiness and see
`"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE"` after 60 seconds.

I, then fire some GET/POST requests to service.

Expected:
Service unavailable message

Actual:
GET/POST endpoints return data as usual

Is the behavior expected. Please comment.

Sample liveness/readiness probe yaml

```
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              value: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            path: /actuator/health/liveness
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        name: sample-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              value: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            path: /actuator/health/readiness
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 140
          periodSeconds: 20
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
```

Comment: Hi, to better understand the setup and the workload you are having, please add the [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you pass the `Deployment` `YAML` manifest (the `probe` part especially). Also when you are sending the request, does the `Pod IP` is visible in the `kubectl get endpoint`?

Comment: Hi, Added yaml part. Once the actuator/health returns SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE `kubectl get endpoint` , does not show `Pod Ip` (`kubectl describe ep` shows `Pod Ip` moved to `NotReadyAddresses`)

Comment: To progress this troubleshooting further, please update your question with following information. 1. `$ kubectl get pods`, 2.  `$ kubectl get services`, 3.  `$ kubectl get endpoints`, 4. After you've changed the app to refuse traffic, what is the HTTP code that is being sent on the `/actuator/health/*` path**s**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior as:

- `$ kubectl port-forward service/SERVICE_NAME LOCAL_PORT:TARGET_PORT`

is not considering the state of the `Pod` when doing a port forwarding (directly connects to a `Pod`).

---

#### Explanation

There is already a great answer which pointed me on further investigation here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Does kubectl port-forward ignore loadBalance services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941521/12257134)*

Let's assume that you have a `Deployment` with a `readinessProbe` (in this example probe will never succeed):

- `$ kubectl get pods, svc` (redacted not needed part)

```sh
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-64ff4d8749-7khht    0/1     Running   0          97m
pod/nginx-deployment-64ff4d8749-bklnf    0/1     Running   0          97m
pod/nginx-deployment-64ff4d8749-gsmml    0/1     Running   0          97m

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/nginx                ClusterIP   10.32.31.105   <none>        80/TCP      97m
```

- `$ kubectl describe endpoints nginx`

```sh
Name:         nginx
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          <none>
  NotReadyAddresses:  10.36.0.62,10.36.0.63,10.36.0.64 # <-- IMPORTANT
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    <unset>  80    TCP

Events:  <none>
```

As you can see all of the `Pods` are not in `Ready` state and the `Service` will not send the traffic to it. This can be seen in a following scenario ( create a test `Pod` that will try to `curl` the `Service`):

- `$ kubectl run -it --rm nginx-check --image=nginx -- /bin/bash`
- `$ curl nginx.default.svc.cluster.local`

```sh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nginx.default.svc.cluster.local port 80: Connection refused
```

Using `kubectl port-forward`:

- `$ kubectl port-forward service/nginx 8080:80`
- `$ curl localhost:8080`

```sh
<-- REDACTED --> 
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>
<-- REDACTED -->
```

More light can be shed on why it happened by getting more verbose output from the command:

- `kubectl port-forward service/nginx 8080:80 -v=6` (the number can be higher)

```sh
I0606 21:29:24.986382    7556 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /SOME_PATH/.kube/config
I0606 21:29:25.041784    7556 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://API_IP/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/nginx 200 OK in 51 milliseconds
I0606 21:29:25.061334    7556 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://API_IP/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dnginx 200 OK in 18 milliseconds
I0606 21:29:25.098363    7556 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://API_IP/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx-deployment-64ff4d8749-7khht 200 OK in 18 milliseconds
I0606 21:29:25.164402    7556 round_trippers.go:444] POST https://API_IP/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx-deployment-64ff4d8749-7khht/portforward 101 Switching Protocols in 62 milliseconds
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
```

What happened:

- `kubectl` requested the information about the `Service`: `nginx`
- `kubectl` used the `selector` associated with the `Service` and looked for `Pods` with the same `selector` (`nginx`)
- `kubectl` chose a single `Pod` and port-forwarded to it.

The `Nginx` welcome page showed as the `port-forward` connected directly to a `Pod` and not to a `Service`.

---

Additional reference:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Issues: kubectl port-forward should allow forwarding to a Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180)*
- `$ kubectl port-forward --help`

> # Listen on port 8443 locally, forwarding to the targetPort of the service's port named "https" in a **pod selected by
> the service**
>
> > `kubectl port-forward service/myservice 8443:https`